# To grep string from file and read first matching string with full variable name

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I have file named file.txt, i am trying to read string first search which matches my pattern search from the file. The problem here is with my command entire line is printed. where i am looking for that variable which matches with search pattern with its full variable name, in this example it is **warning_duration="";** where my search pattern is **duration *=**.i have posted the command i tried to read result also with expected result.

Please help !!!

**file.txt**

```
    warning_type="";warning_threshold="";warning_duration="";oemhp_power_micro_ver="";previous_warning_threshold="";
    duration=19;
    duration  =1;
```

**commands i tried :**

```
cat  file.txt | grep -m1 "duration *="

warning_type="";warning_threshold="";warning_duration="";oemhp_power_micro_ver="";previous_warning_threshold="";
```

```
cat  file.txt | grep -oP -m1 "duration *="

duration=
```

```
expected result:-

warning_duration="";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `grep` command:

```sh
grep -m1 -woE "[_[:alnum:]]*duration *=[^;]*" file

warning_duration=""
```

**Details:**

- `-o`: Only show matches
- `-E`: Enable extended regex
- `-w`: Word search
- `[_[:alnum:]]*`: Match 0 or more of a `_` or alphanumeric characters
- `duration *=`: Match `duration` followed by 0 or more spaces and `=`
- `[^;]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `;`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Simple explanation would be; using `match` function to match regex `;[_[:alnum:]]+duration=""` to get required value by OP eg--> `warning_duration=""`

```
awk 'match($0,/;[_[:alnum:]]+duration=""/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

With GNU `grep` and with your shown samples you could try following.

```
grep -oP '.*?;.*?;\K[_[:alnum:]]+duration=""' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using GNU `grep`'s `-oP` option to match exact match and to enable PCRE regex here. In regex mentioning non-greedy matches to match till 2nd semi-colon and forgetting(removing) matched values by `\K` option and matching alphanumeric9with `_`) ` or more occurrences along with duration="" to get the matched value in current line.

Comment: the matching pattern should be only duration="", in your case its _duration=""

Comment: @AmithKotian, will `_` will come each time before duration or any other things may come also?

Comment: if you see the contents of file duration wont start with _duration. the search pattern should be always duration.

Comment: @AmithKotian, but your expected output is `warning_duration="";` right. Could you please elaborate more on this one?

Comment: yes correct, consider scenario where i grepped pattern duration from file2.txt and that resulted output i need to search in another file1.txt. so always the pattern from file2.txt will be duration.

Comment: @AmithKotian, ok, could you please try both of my solutions and let me know if those helps you, thank you.